# EF Core como incrementar uma lista de objetos já gravados

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Estou implementando uma Web Api e estou usando o EF Core na camada de infra.
Tenho as entidades relacionadas Tabela e TabelaPrecoItem, gostaria de saber se para incrementar a propriedade TabelaPrecoItem de uma entidade Tabela que já esteja gravada, preciso fazer alguma configuração especifica?

Estou fazendo assim:

```
   public override void Add(TabelaPreco tabela)
        {

            if (_dbSet.Any(tb => tb.Id == tabela.Id))
            {
                var table = _dbSet.Where(tb => tb.Id == tabela.Id)
                    .Include(tbi => tbi.Items).First();

                table.Items = tabela.Items;

                _dbSet.Update(table);

             }
            else
            {
                _dbSet.Add(tabela);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

No TypeConfiguration

```
  builder.HasMany(p => p.Items)
.WithOne(itens => itens.TabelaPreco)
.HasForeignKey(fk => fk.TabelaPrecoId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acreditava que o ef faria a incrementação da lista automaticamente, mas pelo que vi, ele não faz. Então resolvi isso com um "foreach" para verificar se o item não existe e adicioná-lo e com o método CurrentValues.SetValues para editar os itens existentes.

```
                foreach (var item in tabela.Items)
                {
                    var ItemExisting = _context.Set<TabelaPrecoItem>().Find(item.Id);

                    if (ItemExisting == null)
                    {
                        _context.TabelaPrecoItem.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _context.Entry(ItemExisting).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                    }
                }
/*...*/

   _context.SaveChanges();
```